# spring mvc controller coroutine suspend function throws IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-mvc

Spring 5.2 brought coroutines support to spring-mvc controllers.
However getting it to work seems not so simple. As I keep getting a stack trace.

I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
class MyController {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController::class.java)
    @RequestMapping(path = ["/execute"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    fun execute(): CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ControllerResult>> {
        return GlobalScope.future {
            logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
            delay(10)
            logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
            ResponseEntity.ok(ControllerResult("test"))
    }    
    @GetMapping(path = ["/executeCo"])
    suspend fun executeCo(): ResponseEntity<ControllerResult> {
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
        delay(10)
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ControllerResult("test"))
    }
}
```

I am testing this with junit 5 and MockMvc. 
From the test GET /execute can be called and returns perfectly. 
Calling GET /executeCo causes the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface kotlin.coroutines.Continuation

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockHttpServletRequestDsl.perform$spring_test(MockHttpServletRequestDsl.kt:207)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcExtensionsKt.get(MockMvcExtensions.kt:32)
    at be.tim.spring52coroutines.MyControllerTest.callCo$spring52coroutines(MyControllerTest.kt:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kotlin.coroutines.Continuation.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216)
    ... 74 more
```

I already added dependencies on:

- spring-webmvc 5.2.0-M1
- spring-webflux 5.2.0-M1
- kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 1.3.31
- kotlin-reflect 1.3.31
- kotlinx-coroutines-core 1.2.1
- kotlinx-coroutines-reactor 1.2.1

Am I missing a dependency or something else (maven compiler plugin, ..)?
The complete code can be found here: https://github.com/codingtim/spring-5.2-coroutines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Framework 5.2 upcoming coroutines support only targets Spring WebFlux, not Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

The most important is NOT TO USE suspend in yoour fun

Use mono

```
@RestController
class MyController {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController::class.java)
    @RequestMapping(path = ["/execute"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    


    fun execute(): CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ControllerResult>> = {
        return GlobalScope.future {
            logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
            delay(10)
            logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
            ResponseEntity.ok(ControllerResult("test"))
    }    
    @GetMapping(path = ["/executeCo"])
    fun executeCo(): Mono<ResponseEntity<ControllerResult>>  = mono {
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
        delay(10)
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ControllerResult("test"))
    }
}
```

But.. I had problems with the test.
Then I used runBlocking

```
   fun execute(): CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ControllerResult>> = {
        return GlobalScope.future {
            logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
            delay(10)
            logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
            ResponseEntity.ok(ControllerResult("test"))
    }    
    @GetMapping(path = ["/executeCo"])
    fun executeCo(): ResponseEntity<ControllerResult>  = runBlocking {
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
        delay(10)
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().name)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ControllerResult("test"))
    }
}
```